# Detect Siri Remote from iPhone via Bluetooth

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, apple-tv, siri-remote

Is it possible to detect the Apple TV 4 Siri Remote from an iOS application using `CoreBluetooth`? I'm able to detect the Apple TV, but I'm not having any luck detecting the Siri Remote. The [Siri Remote](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MLLC2LL/A/siri-remote) uses Bluetooth 4.0 so I'm assuming it is detectable. Ideally, I'd like to detect the Siri Remote even if it's already paired with the Apple TV.

Simply being able to detect any signal from the Siri Remote/know it's in the vicinity of the users iPhone is what I'm after.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@import CoreBluetooth;

@interface ViewController () <CBPeripheralDelegate, CBCentralManagerDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController {
    CBCentralManager *btManager;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    btManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
}

#pragma mark - CBCentralManagerDelegate Methods

-(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {
    NSLog(@"peripheral name: %@", peripheral.name);
    NSLog(@"peripheral services: %@", peripheral.services);
    NSLog(@"peripheral identifier: %@", peripheral.identifier);
    NSLog(@"peripheral state: %ld", (long)peripheral.state);
    NSLog(@"RSSI: %@ \n\n", RSSI);
}

-(void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central {
    NSString *nsLogMessage;

    switch (central.state) {
        case CBCentralManagerStateUnknown: {
            nsLogMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"State unknown, update imminent."];
            break;
        }
        case CBCentralManagerStateResetting: {
            nsLogMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The connection with the system service was momentarily lost, update imminent."];
            break;
        }
        case CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported: {
            nsLogMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The platform doesn't support Bluetooth Low Energy"];
            break;
        }
        case CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized: {
            nsLogMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The app is not authorized to use Bluetooth Low Energy"];
            break;
        }
        case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff: {
            nsLogMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bluetooth is currently powered off."];
            break;
        }
        case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn: {
            nsLogMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bluetooth is currently powered on and available to use."];

            NSDictionary *scanningOptions = @{CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: @YES};
            [btManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:scanningOptions];
            break;
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", nsLogMessage);
}
```

Comment: Just a hunch. Have you tried "unpairing/disconnecting" the Siri remote before you do your scan - maybe it's not advertising?

Comment: @n3rd4n1 I have not. Ideally, I'd like to detect the Siri Remote even if it's already paired with the Apple TV.

Comment: According to a French Article on SiriMote.app, you would have to unfair before, and to a special manipulation to activate a discovering mode: http://www.macg.co/logiciels/2015/12/sirimote-controlez-votre-mac-avec-la-siri-remote-92071 You may find more info about that with SiriMote

Comment: @Larme thank you. I don't require pairing for my purposes though. Simply being able to detect any signal from the Siri Remote/know it's in the vicinity of the users iPhone is what I'm after.